# Scala: InputStream to Array[Byte]

Tags: scala, arrays, inputstream

With Scala, what is the best way to read from an InputStream to a bytearray?

I can see that you can convert an InputStream to char array

```
Source.fromInputStream(is).toArray()
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

How about:

```
Stream.continually(is.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte).toArray
```

Update: use LazyList instead of `Stream` (since `Stream` is deprecated in Scala 3)

```
LazyList.continually(is.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte).toArray
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between this and the variant in the question?

Comment: @Jus12 I was looking for a byte array. What I have in the question, is a way to obtain the char array.

Comment: Won't that create a huge linked list, then convert it to an array? That doesn't look very efficient, in time or memory.

Comment: It looks like this does not create a linked list after all. [Stream.continually](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator$) produces an iterator, and `takeWhile` and `map` seem to convert iterators to iterators. E.g. evaluating `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, -1).iterator.takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte)` in a Scala 2.9.3 REPL gives me `Iterator[Byte] = non-empty iterator`.

Comment: This seemed to cause OOM errors for me.  Things were GC'd eventually but the spikes were beyond what my server could handle.

Comment: @JamesWard You can use KevinWright's method instead.

Comment: Looks like pretty much the same thing as this.  I used @TimT's answer and it seems to be working without OOMs.

Answer (score 47):

Just removed bottleneck in our server code by replacing

```
Stream.continually(request.getInputStream.read()).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte).toArray
```

with

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream)
```

Or in pure Scala:

```
def bytes(in: InputStream, initSize: Int = 8192): Array[Byte] = {
  var buf = new Array[Byte](initSize)
  val step = initSize
  var pos, n = 0
  while ({
    if (pos + step > buf.length) buf = util.Arrays.copyOf(buf, buf.length << 1)
    n = in.read(buf, pos, step)
    n != -1
  }) pos += n
  if (pos != buf.length) buf = util.Arrays.copyOf(buf, pos)
  buf
}
```

Do not forget to close an opened input stream in any case:

```
val in = request.getInputStream
try bytes(in) finally in.close()
```

Comment: That's org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray, in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: This definitely feels faster. Anyone done any benchmarks or tests with larger files?

Comment: Thank you. I had huge issues with GC Overhead errors running this with Apache Spark, where 90% of the time my tasks spent in GC. Replacing with `toByteArray` massively sped up things.

Comment: It's important to point out how this solution can really drastically out-perform the alternatives, where you have things like `map(_.toByte)` iterating over the input byte-by-byte... Do this you are working with big-data!

Answer (score 20):

In a similar vein to Eastsun's answer...  I started this as a comment, but it ended up getting just a bit to long!

I'd caution against using `Stream`, if holding a reference to the head element then streams can easily consume a lot of memory.

Given that you're only going to read in the file once, then `Iterator` is a much better choice:

```
def inputStreamToByteArray(is: InputStream): Array[Byte] =
  Iterator continually is.read takeWhile (-1 !=) map (_.toByte) toArray
```

Answer (score 14):

```
import scala.tools.nsc.io.Streamable
Streamable.bytes(is)
```

Don't remember how recent that is: probably measured in days.  Going back to 2.8, it's more like

```
new Streamable.Bytes { def inputStream() = is } toByteArray
```

Comment: Is it safe to use stuff from scala.tools packages? Are they even a part of the standard library?

Comment: No.  But if you want to know how to write it, there it is.

Comment: It seems to have moved to the more standard `scala.reflect.io` package now.

Comment: `scala.reflect.io.Streamable.bytes`

Answer (score 11):

With [Scala IO](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io/), this should work:

```
def inputStreamToByteArray(is: InputStream): Array[Byte] = 
   Resource.fromInputStream(in).byteArray
```

Answer (score 7):

With [better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/), you can simply do `is.bytes`

Comment: better.files should just be in std lib. It is so much better. Also if you want `Array[Byte]` you need to use `is.byteArray` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Source.fromInputStream(is).map(_.toByte).toArray

Comment: This fails on binary/false encoded text files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327536/malformedinputexception-when-trying-to-read-entire-file

Answer (score 2):

How about buffered version of solution based on streams plus ByteArraOutputStream to minimize boilerplate around final array growing?

```
val EOF: Int = -1

def readBytes(is: InputStream, bufferSize: Int): Array[Byte] = {
  val buf = Array.ofDim[Byte](bufferSize)
  val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferSize)

  Stream.continually(is.read(buf)) takeWhile { _ != EOF } foreach { n =>
    out.write(buf, 0, n)
  }

  out.toByteArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using scalaz-stream:

```
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.stream._
import scodec.bits.ByteVector

def allBytesR(is: InputStream): Process[Task, ByteVector] =
  io.chunkR(is).evalMap(_(4096)).reduce(_ ++ _).lastOr(ByteVector.empty)
```

Comment: probably no reason to reduce, that would defeat the incremental nature of streams

Comment: The reason is that the question asks for a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Since JDK 9:

```
is.readAllBytes()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do using Google API ByteStreams

```
com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
```

pass the stream to ByteStreams.toByteArray method for conversion

```
ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def inputStreamToByteArray(is: InputStream): Array[Byte] = {
    val buf = ListBuffer[Byte]()
    var b = is.read()
    while (b != -1) {
        buf.append(b.byteValue)
        b = is.read()
    }
    buf.toArray
}
```

Comment: Does List[Byte] have a method "add"?