# How to convert request.body to a byte array in order to calculate MD5?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm creating a scala function in a Play! application that authenticates requests to my web-service. The authentication is basically an HMAC authentication. The method receives the type of bodyParser to be used. Since I don't know the type of the -bodyParser, how can I convert request.body to a generic Array[Byte] on which I can run my MD5 processing?

```
def Authenticated[T](authType : AuthenticationType, bodyParser : BodyParser[T])(f : (Request[T]) => Result) = {

    Action(bodyParser) { request => 

      // Authentication logic starts here

      // TODO: Something like: var bodyData : Array[Byte] = request.body.toByteArray()

      // The rest is easy...
      var contentMD5 = calculateMD5(bodyDat)
      f(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905393/scala-inputstream-to-arraybyte

Answer (score 0):

Any request body received by Play can be parsed to a [`Http.RawBuffer`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/mvc/RawBuffer.html) which can give a pure a raw byte array representation of your request body.

The line of code you're looking for is

```
var bodyData : Array[Byte] = request.body.asRaw.asBytes()
```

Comment: That's only true when the type of the BodyParser is AnyContent. Since in my case the type of the BodyParser is T, it also means that request.body is of type T, and since T is unknown, it doesn't have a 'asRaw' method.

Comment: I'm not sure of the Scala specifics in play here (pun intended), but isn't it a feasible solution to change `T` to `T extends AnyContent` here? Now you're asking how to convert any arbitrary JVM type to a pure byte representation, which of course won't have a trivial answer. Whatever type you get should at least extend from a base class that gives you some basics to help the conversion to a byte array.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, hence the question. Something with iteratees on the request maybe.(http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Iteratees).